# how to make a loop column in R?

Tags: r

I want to make a new column loop as below:

```
Household   person    trip    ZoneOfHome    start_zone   end_zone
   1           1        1      22              22           13
   1           1        2      22              13           22
   1           1        3      22              22           34
   1           1        4      22              34           22 
   1           2        1      22              22           13
   1           2        2      22              13           22
   2           1        1      15              15           15
   2           1        2      15              15           15
   2           1        3      15              15           45
   2           1        4      15              45           15
   3           1        1      17              6            17
   3           1        2      17              17           10
   3           1        3      17              10           17
```

The first column is the index of the household. the second column is the index of person in that household . the third column is the index of trip of each day in each family during a day. the zoneOfHome is the zone of the home of that household. start_zone is a zone that a person start his/her trip from there and end_zone is the zone of a place that a person travel to there.
A loop is a sequence of trips which starts from home and ends at home.
I want a new column 'loop' which determine loop of each trip of household member. There are 3 different situation I show them in 3 different household.

1-In the above example the zone of home of the first family is 22. the first trip of the first person is from home to zone 13. then from 13 to home. so the first loop of this person is:

`22 -> 13 -> 22`

the second loop of this person is `22->34 -> 22`

the loop of second person is `22 -> 13 -> 22`

2-the second household is a little complicated. the zone of home is 15. the trip of the first person is from 15 to 15. (so a place close to home). it dose not mean that 15-> 15 is a loop. 
the person goes from 15 to 15 and back from 15 to 15 so the loop is

`15 -> 15 -> 15 >- 15`

and his second loop is `15 -> 45 -> 15`.

3- in the third household the first trip of the first person is not from home. So we remove the first trip and start from a trip which is based home. the loop is `17 -> 10 -> 17`

```
Household   person    trip    ZoneOfHome    start_zone   end_zone       loop
   1           1        1      22              22           13            1
   1           1        2      22              13           22            1
   1           1        3      22              22           34            2
   1           1        4      22              34           22            2
   1           2        1      22              22           13            1
   1           2        2      22              13           22            1
   2           1        1      15              15           15            1
   2           1        2      15              15           15            1
   2           1        3      15              15           45            2
   2           1        4      15              45           15            2
   3           1        1      17              6            17            -
   3           1        2      17              17           10            1
   3           1        3      17              10           17            1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a challenging question. I have found a solution which uses `cumsum()` and `rowid()` to return the expected result for the given sample dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[, loop := cumsum((ZoneOfHome == start_zone) - rowid(start_zone, end_zone) + 1L), 
          by = .(Household, person)][]
```

> ```
>     Household person trip ZoneOfHome start_zone end_zone loop
>  1:         1      1    1         22         22       13    1
>  2:         1      1    2         22         13       22    1
>  3:         1      1    3         22         22       34    2
>  4:         1      1    4         22         34       22    2
>  5:         1      2    1         22         22       13    1
>  6:         1      2    2         22         13       22    1
>  7:         2      1    1         15         15       15    1
>  8:         2      1    2         15         15       15    1
>  9:         2      1    3         15         15       45    2
> 10:         2      1    4         15         45       15    2
> 11:         3      1    1         17          6       17    0
> 12:         3      1    2         17         17       10    1
> 13:         3      1    3         17         10       17    1
> ```

#### Explanation

First, we create a running count for each `person` in a `household` whenever the person is leaving their home zone:

```
DT[, loop1 := cumsum(ZoneOfHome == start_zone), by = .(Household, person)][]
```

> ```
>     Household person trip ZoneOfHome start_zone end_zone loop1
>  1:         1      1    1         22         22       13     1
>  2:         1      1    2         22         13       22     1
>  3:         1      1    3         22         22       34     2
>  4:         1      1    4         22         34       22     2
>  5:         1      2    1         22         22       13     1
>  6:         1      2    2         22         13       22     1
>  7:         2      1    1         15         15       15     1
>  8:         2      1    2         15         15       15     2
>  9:         2      1    3         15         15       45     3
> 10:         2      1    4         15         45       15     3
> 11:         3      1    1         17          6       17     0
> 12:         3      1    2         17         17       10     1
> 13:         3      1    3         17         10       17     1
> ```

This comes pretty close to the expected result except for the case where the destination of a trip is located in the home zone. So, we need a correction for this case. The correction is based on the observation that `start_zone` and `end_zone` of a *home zone loop* is identical in subsequent rows. This can be counted with help of the `rowid()` function which increases a counter whenever one of the parameters change:

```
DT[, corr_local := cumsum(rowid(start_zone, end_zone) - 1L), by = .(Household, person)][]
```

> ```
>     Household person trip ZoneOfHome start_zone end_zone loop1 corr_local
>  1:         1      1    1         22         22       13     1          0
>  2:         1      1    2         22         13       22     1          0
>  3:         1      1    3         22         22       34     2          0
>  4:         1      1    4         22         34       22     2          0
>  5:         1      2    1         22         22       13     1          0
>  6:         1      2    2         22         13       22     1          0
>  7:         2      1    1         15         15       15     1          0
>  8:         2      1    2         15         15       15     2          1
>  9:         2      1    3         15         15       45     3          1
> 10:         2      1    4         15         45       15     3          1
> 11:         3      1    1         17          6       17     0          0
> 12:         3      1    2         17         17       10     1          0
> 13:         3      1    3         17         10       17     1          0
> ```

Finally, both helper columns need to be combined

```
DT[, loop := loop1 - corr_local, by = .(Household, person)][]
```

> ```
>     Household person trip ZoneOfHome start_zone end_zone loop1 corr_local loop
>  1:         1      1    1         22         22       13     1          0    1
>  2:         1      1    2         22         13       22     1          0    1
>  3:         1      1    3         22         22       34     2          0    2
>  4:         1      1    4         22         34       22     2          0    2
>  5:         1      2    1         22         22       13     1          0    1
>  6:         1      2    2         22         13       22     1          0    1
>  7:         2      1    1         15         15       15     1          0    1
>  8:         2      1    2         15         15       15     2          1    1
>  9:         2      1    3         15         15       45     3          1    2
> 10:         2      1    4         15         45       15     3          1    2
> 11:         3      1    1         17          6       17     0          0    0
> 12:         3      1    2         17         17       10     1          0    1
> 13:         3      1    3         17         10       17     1          0    1
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread(
"Household   person    trip    ZoneOfHome    start_zone   end_zone
   1           1        1      22              22           13
   1           1        2      22              13           22
   1           1        3      22              22           34
   1           1        4      22              34           22 
   1           2        1      22              22           13
   1           2        2      22              13           22
   2           1        1      15              15           15
   2           1        2      15              15           15
   2           1        3      15              15           45
   2           1        4      15              45           15
   3           1        1      17              6            17
   3           1        2      17              17           10
   3           1        3      17              10           17")
```

Comment: Had a solution ready, but this one puts mine to shame. I need to have a deep dive into data.table, it seems powerful

Comment: @Mr.Rlover Thank you. I have used `data.table` here because of it's `rowid()` function and because I am more acquainted with `data.table` than with `dplyr`. However, I believ this approach can be implemented in `dplyr` as well.

Comment: @Uwe I notice my data set is more complicated. could you please tell me how about if I have one more column called purpose of trip. Now a loop is start  when `zone=start_zone, until `zone=end_zone` & purpose=home?

Comment: @elham, Please, post a new question with an appropriate sample dataset including the expected result. Otherwise, it is impossible for me to verify that my suggestions are correct. Thank you.

Comment: @Uwe could you please see this post?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60330449/how-define-a-new-column-with-respect-of-4-columns